# How to perform site redirection in prestashop site based on jquery condition to its multishop url

Tags: .htaccess, prestashop

I need to redirect my prestashop site root url based on a jquery condition.If i have done by using the below script my site keep on loading with multishop url matched to the condition.But the same script is working fine, if i have given other url like(for ex:https://www.google.co.in/) than multishop url.why is it so?Why based on the jquery condition my site keep on performing redirection with multishop url.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var browsername=navigator.appName; 
if( browsername == "Microsoft Internet Explorer" )
{ 
   window.location="http://www.mysite.com/shop1";
}

else
{
  window.location="http://www.mysite.com/shop2";
}
//-->
</script>
```

Comment: You're using browser sniffing??? WTF? Is it 1997 again?

Comment: Kindly consider the logic alone based on requirement.Now i have updated the code.@Rory McCrossan

Comment: Ok, edited previous comment to be more obvious what I meant.

Comment: Have you got my requirement exactly?Whether this continous redirect issue is because of htaccess file?do u have any suggestion to overcome it?@Rorry McCrossan